# AWS Cloudformation combination of CommaDelimitedList, fn:if and fn:select

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a cfn stack. Template takes one/two values as input from parameter section.if i am passing two values from parameter same reading in resource section its working fine. but if i pass one it is breaking.

Use Case :- I want to pass two values from parameters and read them in iam policy. if user passed one value it should use   {"Ref" : "AWS::NoValue"}. but i am keep on getting

**Template error: Fn::Select cannot select nonexistent value at index 1**

here is the template -

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Template creates a IAMUser and attach a ListALLBuckets/ReadOnly Access Policy to it.",
    "Parameters": {
        "UserName": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Enter User Name"
        },
        "S3Bucket": {
            "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
            "Description": "Select Bucket Name to Associate with the policy",
            "Default": ""
        }
    },
    "Conditions": {
        "CreateSomeResource": {
            "Fn::Not": [{
                "Fn::Equals": [{
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            {
                                "Ref": "S3Bucket"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    ""
                ]
            }]
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "SomeUserName": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::User",
            "Properties": {
                "UserName":  {  "Ref": "UserName"}
            }
        },
        "SomeUserPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
            "Properties": {
                "Groups": [],
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [{
                            "Sid": "ListAllBuckets",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                            ],
                            "Resource": "*"
                        }, {
                            "Sid": "ReadOnlyAccess",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                                "s3:GetObject"
                            ],
                            "Resource": [

                                {
                                    "Fn::If": [
                                        "CreateSomeResource",
                                        {
                                            "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::",
                                                {
                                                    "Fn::Select": ["0",
                                                        {
                                                            "Ref": "S3Bucket"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]]
                                        },
                                        {"Ref" : "AWS::NoValue"}
                                    ]
                                },

                                {
                                    "Fn::If": [
                                        "CreateSomeResource",
                                        {
                                            "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::",
                                                {
                                                    "Fn::Select": ["1",
                                                        {
                                                            "Ref": "S3Bucket"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]]
                                        },
                                        {"Ref" : "AWS::NoValue"}
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }

                    ]
                },
                "PolicyName": "ReadOnly",

                "Users": [{
                    "Ref": "SomeUserName"
                }]
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "UserName": {
            "Description": "Name of the Created User",
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "UserName"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `S3Bucket` has only one value, then this:

```
"Fn::Select": ["1",
    {
        "Ref": "S3Bucket"
    }
```

is obviously invalid. Sadly, it does not matter that you have `CreateSomeResource` condition there. The select must be valid whether the condition is true or false.

Probably the easiet solution would be to pass the buckets as **two separate parameters**, `S3Bucket1` and `S3Bucket2` and have respective conditions for each of them.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but.. user can pass as multiple values not limited to two.. 
Seems with the Fn:Select limitation its not possible.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html

Comment: @ShubhamJain I meant that select 1 will be invalid if your array has only one element.